# How to store my App files as Public in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio-4.1

I am a beginner in Android Studio. I created one App where I am uploading Magazines Monthly, so that all the users of App can see. As of now I am uploading the files in storage/emulated/0/Downloads/Appname/Magazines. But where to upload the files, so it can be viewed by everyone(I mean to save in a public)..if someone can answer it will be a great help. Thanks in advance...